# What is the correct action for this reopen review audit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, review-audits

I failed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/18214374), but it seems like a clear "reopen" vote to me. It was closed as "unclear", but the edit fixes that in my opinion.

I typically vote to reopen if there's was a genuine effort to improve the question with an edit. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are they asking how to do it or are they asking if there's a better way to do it? Does the query that was added in the edit work or not? I'm personally not sure what exactly they're expecting out of that question, if it is a question. *(But then again SQL isn't something I know a lot about. I would personally have skipped that review)*.

Comment: I didn't test the SQL query. Are saying that the reason this should be closed as unclear is that the SQL is invalid?

Comment: It looks like the question would be a better fit at the code review site, I read the question as the user trying to find a better way to solve a issue that he/she already has solved

Comment: I don't know if the SQL is invalid, I'm not sure if they're asking about how to fix it or how to improve it.

Comment: Apparently nobody is exactly sure what the OP is really asking. The "unclear" close reason seems to apply, then. If you understand the question, maybe you can explain what is says, and help the OP edit their question into shape.

Comment: The question is clear. Generally speaking, asking for a "better way" to do something is too broad however in this case the answer is trivial and simple so I don't know. I think the decision about what to do with this question is borderline and it shouldn't be an audit.

Comment: This question has been used for [2 audits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47402002/timeline). 1 close audit and 1 reopen audit. Both audits were failed as a result of the reviewer indicating the question should be open.

Comment: "genuine effort to improve the question" is something to promote but not by opening unclear questions, which should be closed.

Comment: To me the question becomes quite clear after the edit. Also, this is not merely about asking "How do I improve this?" - they have included their attempt, and they are asking for a cleaner query. To me, that is not a "too broad" question. Possible answers could be, (A) your attempt is quite efficient, you don't need to improve it. Or, (B) Instead of typing 'red' 9 times in the query, you can make it a variable, and that should simplify the query. Or, something better. Basically it is answerable.

Answer (score 3):

> I typically vote to reopen if there's was a genuine effort to improve the question with an edit. Am I wrong?

Since you failed the audit, at least the people who performed the original review disagreed with you.  And I guess I do, too.

"Genuine effort" is not an appropriate standard.  A question should be reopened if it has been updated to become a good (or at least passable) one.  If an edit does not achieve that then reopening the question doesn't do anyone much good, no matter how much effort seems to have gone into the edit.    There's a decent chance that doing so is actually harmful, for if the edited version reenters the close queue then it requires more reviewer attention, and it probably ends up closed again anyway.

With respect to the particular audit, I agree with you that the edit showed genuine effort, and even that it improved the question, but the edited question remains unclear as far as I am concerned.  What does the OP actually want to know?  Moreover, inasmuch as it seems that the OP may have a working solution already, it seems the question might not even be on-topic for SO in the first place.

Comment: I mentioned _geniune effort to improve the question_ because that's something that is almost never the case in the reopen queue. The question was edited to add sql and sample data, exactly as suggested by a commenter. Since the OP responds to comments asking for clarifications, It's unreasonable to assume that the question would go right back to the close queue.

Comment: Why would a "working solution" make a question off topic for stack overflow? I can't see any reason why this would not be on-topic according to the help center article. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @HåkenLid, having a working solution means that there is no problem to ask (on SO) about.  Now, it is fair to consider *to what* the OP may have a solution.  For example, if he gets the right answer, but needs to get it ten times faster, then he does not have a working solution in the sense I mean.  But general "how do I make this working code better" questions, such as the one at issue here, belong on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not SO.

Comment: As far as whether the question would return to the close queue, you should review based on the question *as it is presented to you*.  If you perform a reopen review where the question isn't quite there yet, but you think the OP is prepared to get it the rest of the way to where it needs to be, then you should consider adding a comment to that effect to the question.  In any case, whether a question actually returns to the close queue is a side issue.  If you allow a question to be reopened that is not up to SO standards then you have shirked your duty to the community.